# User Sortable List on Landing Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, jquery, landing-page

I want to display an ordered list of items taken from a Data Extension via a Landing Page. Then allow the user to re-order the items via jquery and save the new order back into the Data Extension.

I have the jquery piece working to allow the re-order but I am struggling to get the updated order back into the DE.

Does anyone have an example or solution for this?

Comment: Why does it need to be sorted in the Data Extension?

Comment: The context is a preference centre, so I want to keep a record of the user preferences in order of importance. If their preferences change, I want to store that change. It doesn't need to be sorted in the DE, but I need the order stored so that I can display it sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include an index or ordinal position for each row -- similar to this [**Data Tables**](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) example:

[image: data tables index example]

You can just store the ordinal position in the Data Extension and retrieve it in  order using the [**LookupOrderRows()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/) function (or the SSJS [**Lookup()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/#section_23) function) in your page.

Comment: Thanks Adam, my issue is how I get the new order from the client side jquery result into the Data Extension. Once it's in the DE I am fine.